# How to plot a map in R Studio of Argentina`s states and write over the map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, latitude-longitude

I wanna plot a map of Argentina that contains the limits between the different states (Provinces) of Argentina. After that, I want to write some things over special latitudes and longitudes in the map.
Is there any way to do that?
I only found ways to plot Argentina that do NOT contain the limits between provinces.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tmap` solution:

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)

# loading shapefile 
provinces <- st_read(dsn = "arg_adm_unhcr2017_shp/arg_admbnda_adm1_unhcr2017.shp") %>% st_as_sf()

tm_shape(provinces) +
    tm_fill(col = "gray") +
    tm_text("ADM1_ES", size = 1) +
tm_borders(lwd = 1, col = "black")
```

The shapefile containing the province borders is available from: https://data.humdata.org/dataset/argentina-administrative-level-0-boundaries.

[image]